# Rails 3 - Looping through DB records, one record has a HASH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a database with records like the following
Table: AuditLog
Fields: ID | USERID | TYPE | TIME | DATA

```
id:1, userId:1, type:PHOTO, time:2008-10-15 12:00:00, data:{photoId:2089, photoName:A trip to the beach}
```

Lets say the database had 50 records, with Rails How can I loop through the results as follows:

- id, user_id, data.photoID, data.PhotoName

The main thing I don't get is how to extract what's inside the data column, the has that's inserted int the db field.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of results like this you would do something like the following:

```
@results.each do |result|
  p result.data.photoId
end
```

You can certainly get fancier but hopefully this will get you along for now.

Comment: That's incredible,,, bonus point for if you can share how to store the data field like it is above. thanks!

Comment: Probably just need to marshall the data before it goes into the database. Check out this link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html specifically the section on saving arrays and hashes. Excellent guide.

Comment: @Chuck, just tried the above and it errors? does the p in the front have any significance? I tried it w and w/o and both failed... The error I get is "NoMethodError" undefined method `photo_id' for #<String:0x1033a80f0>

Comment: Use `result.data['photoID']` to index into a Hash object in Ruby.

Comment: @raphomet thanks... I just tried that and it just outputs photoID and not the value in the DB meta field data? I tried it without the ' so just [photoID] and it errors: undefined local variable or method `photoID'

Comment: Am I storing it in the database correctly? {photoID:2089, photoName: "blah"}

Comment: It looks like you converted a JavaScript Object into a string and saved it.  You might have to cast into a Ruby Hash after fetching it out of the database: `JSON.parse(result.data)['photoID']`

Comment: So here's the deal... I haven't built the part that stores the data yet, and that won't be JSON based. How should the data look in data field to be a Ruby HASH?

Comment: Woz, I apologize but I have to go to bed. @raph, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Make the database column a string.  Marshal (which means to serialize a data object into a string) the data using `Marshal.dump(data)`.  When you fetch it back out of the database, you can convert it back into a Hash using `Marshal.load(data)`.

Comment: @Raphomet interesting, I have not heard of the ability to Marshal, google searching to learn more and try it out. Not finding much, know of any tutorials or examples so I can understand the suggestion? or would it be possible to see an example Marshal.dump and load,, and what the data would look like for the above in the database for 1 field? thanks

Comment: Marshaling is dangerous, as it may not be interoperable, and it may differ depending on ruby Ruby version. I preffer YAML or JSON - data lasts longer than applications.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with JSON, seems pretty simple to use... Anyone know about the JSON performance?